# Question about a poisson arrival process

Tags: probability

Q) Let people arrive at a store at times of a homogenous poisson process with an average arrival rate of one every $10$ minutes. Each person spends, independently of the other people, $5\$$ or $10\$$ with probability $1/2$. Let $N$ be the total number of customers and $S$ be the total money spent in a day. Find the covariance of $N$ and $S$.

$N\sim Pois(\frac{1}{10}\times 8\times 60)=Pois(48)$

My question is if $S = \frac{1}{2}\times N\times 5 + \frac{1}{2}\times N\times 10 = \frac{15N}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite... if you know the value of $N$ it is not necessarily true that you automatically know that $S = 15N/2$ because there is some randomness in what the person will spend.

Instead, if $X \sim Binom(N, 1/2)$, then you can say
$$S = 5X + 10(N - X)$$
notice that
$$E(S) = E(E(S|N)) = E(10N - \frac{5N}{2}) = 480 - 120 = 360$$
so you can use this to compute $Cov(N, S) = E(NS) - E(N)E(S)$